# Make table cell clickable in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When the user clicks the tableCell text below, he should be navigated to `http://localhost:3000/crayons/${rows.id}` <- This exists in my react-router-dom

I am not sure how to edit the below code to do the following

```
<TableBody>

{props.rows.slice(page).map(row => (
     <TableCell align="center">{row.crayon_color}</TableCell>

</TableBody>
```

What I tried

```
<TableCell align="center" numeric component="a" href=`http://localhost:3000/crayons/${rows.id}`> {row.crayon_color}</TableCell>
```

Comment: Are you using any sort of router? Is `/crayons` a part of your app? Look into [react-router-dom](https://blog.logrocket.com/react-router-dom-set-up-essential-components-parameterized-routes-505dc93642f1/) You can find the [GitHub repo here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-dom)

Comment: @MattOestreich yes it is part of my react-router-dom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT*** updated live demo to show how to handle dynamic objects in an array.

***EDIT 2*** updated live demo and the code below to reflect how to use URL params with dynamic objects..

---

I believe the easiest way to accomplish this is by using a `<Link/>` component from `react-router-dom`.

[Live Demo Found Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vyprga?embed=1&file=Pages/Home.js)

---

This is what the `BrowserRouter` needs to look like:

```
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route exact path="/crayons" component={Crayons} />
      <Route path="/crayons/:id" component={Crayons} />

      {/* MUST BE THE LAST ROUTE IN THIS LIST!!!! */}
      <Route component={FourZeroFour} />
    </Switch>
```

---

Then inside of your `Crayons.js` page, you can access the URL param, in this case `id` like: `props.match.params.id`..

---

*Demo `Table` code:*

```
// Build 'fake data' for table
const rows = Array.from(Array(10).keys()).map(item => {
  return {
    data: "Crayon",
    count: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
    id: item + 1
  }
})

export default function Home() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Welcome to my app</h1>
      <Paper className={classes.root}>
        <Table className={classes.table}>
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
              <TableCell>Data</TableCell>
              <TableCell>ID</TableCell>
              <TableCell>Count</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
            {rows.map(row => {
              return (
                <TableRow key={row.id}>
                  <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                    {row.id
                      ? <Link to={`/crayons/${row.id}`}>{row.data}</Link>
                      : row.data}
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell>
                    {row.id}
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell>
                    {row.count}
                  </TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              )
            })}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </Paper>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: can you please update the `<Link to="/crayons"` so that it can take dynamic id ?  for example `${row.calories}`

Comment: @JosephAdam let me know if that helps clear things up - I have updated my answer as well as the live demo.

Comment: I am trying to force it to do this `<Link to={\`http://localhost:3000/crayon/${row.id}\`}`

Comment: it worked ! I just had to use `crayon/${row.id}` instead of `http://localhost:3000/crayon/${row.id}`

Comment: Glad you got it working! I also updated my answer with relative code, as well as the Live Demo.  Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Try using a callback for the table cell that pushes the routes into `history`, so with that your code would resemble something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

const ExampleComponent = (props) => {

  // ...other component variables

  callback = () => {
    props.history.push(`crayons/${rows.id}`)
  }

  return (
    <TableCell align="center" onClick={callback}>{row.crayon_color}</TableCell>
  );
}

export default withRouter(ExampleComponent);
```

Comment: I am sorry this will not work because rows doesn't exist, it is row, and that is generated for every table cell. I updated my question maybe that clears it a bit

Comment: In that case, Sangam Rajpara's answer would better suit your needs as it writes the callback within the react component

Comment: that doesnt work as it appears as text between the cells

Answer (score 1):

You can use library [React Router Dom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-dom).

Solution is simple add withRouter HOC to your component.

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-don'


const Component = () => (
    <TableCell align="centre" onClick={()=>props.history.push(`${rows.id}`)}>{row.crayon_color}</TableCell>
)

export default withRouter(Component);
```

Comment: you cannot use `const Component = () => (`  between other  `<TableCell ...` that will actually end up appearing as text in the table in the browser

Comment: I was showing demo how to add HOC withRouter to the component.